# Fiware Orion Context Broker set entity type to "none" if it's not explicit in the body on PUT v2/entities/$id/attrs/$attr_name request

Tags: fiware-orion

In a case that I would like to update value and metadata, if I don't set the attribute type in the request body, it will update attribute type to "none" and I'll lose the information.

I'm not sure if it's should happen. 
This endpoint doesn't allow PATCH requests.

**e.g.:**

I have an attribute called temperature, its type is 'cassius'.

> PUT http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/Room1/attrs/temperature?type=Room

*Body:*

```
{
"value": 20,
"metadata":{"han":"solo"}
}
```

*Representation with cURL:*

```
curl -X PUT -H "Fiware-Service: teste_1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"value": 20, "metadata":{"han":"solo"}
}' "http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/Room1/attrs/temperature?type=Room"
```

After this request, the original attribute type  is gone because it has been set 
to "none", since it's not present on request body was set to none.

PS: I'd not tested with text/plain content type.

Orion Context Broker Info:

```
{
  "orion" : {
  "version" : "1.2.0-next",
  "uptime" : "9 d, 17 h, 27 m, 37 s",
  "git_hash" : "c1a224db08086751f05d471a8b52c0eaec15f3a5",
  "compile_time" : "Thu Aug 4 09:04:12 BRT 2016",
  "compiled_by" : "root"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

if you do a PUT you are replacing the whole attribute and type is reset to "none" by the implementation.

Try to update only the value and type will remain.

http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/Room1/attrs/temperature/value

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I understand, but not agree with that view, doesn't make sense attribute type being changed "by the implementation" aka "by default". 
In a conceptual model, the attribute type represents the structure of top-level concepts it's the fundamental building block for describing the structure of data contained into this an attribute.
To prevent inconsistencies, the attribute type update (or removal) should be strictly requested by the actor when the desired fact. In this case, if I'm updating value and metadata it doesn't mean I want to change the entity type as well.

Comment: To solve that may Orion should have the same call using PATCH verb.

Comment: Yes, adding a PATCH method for the same URL will make the API more flexible. However, by the moment, there are two possible workarounds: 1) the one described by @jose-manuel-cantera in this answer, 2) add "type" to your request.